# while loop does not work if nothing changes to terminate it

Tags: c

I can't quite figure out this while loop. i understand the concept i just don't know what to increase it by. Also, for some reason my running total doesn't work?

the idea behind this is setting a goal of money to save up in a jar. Every time i put a certain amount of money in the jar, i want it to give me the total amount of money in the jar, and also tell me how much more money i need to put in the jar to reach my goal.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int goal;
    int total = 0;
    int deposite;
    int ammountNeeded;

    printf("How much money would you like to save?\n ");
    scanf("%i", &goal);
    printf("How much money are you putting in the jar?\n");
    scanf("i%", &deposite);

    total = total + deposite;
    ammountNeeded = goal - deposite;

    while (goal > total) {
        printf("How much money are you putting in the jar?\n ");
        scanf("i%", &deposite);
        printf("You have saved R%i. ", total);
        printf("You need to save another R%i in order to reach your goal.\n ",ammountNeeded);
    }

    if (total >= goal) {
        printf("Well done! you have sucsessfully saved R%i", goal);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is neither C#, Objective C, or C++. Only apply tags that are actually valid.

Comment: You need to add `deposite` to `total` and store that back into `total`, otherwise the value is never changing and the loop never exits, as you are observing.

Comment: I see several typos.  I don't see any adjustment to `total` or `ammountNeeded` [sic] inside the `while` loop.  Never use `scanf`.

Answer (score 3):

The while loop has a condition. It executes the body as long as the condition is true. In your case, the condition does not change, because none of the 2 variables compared change its value inside the loop. You should either increase total or decrease goal.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
while (goal > total) {
    printf("How much money are you putting in the jar?\n ");
    scanf("i%", &deposite);
    total = total + deposite;    //Add this 
    printf("You have saved R%i. ", total);
    ammountNeeded = goal - total;  // And perhaps add this
    printf("You need to save another R%i in order to reach your goal.\n ",ammountNeeded);

}
```